# Graph Authentication in C# with ClientSecret

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have developed a C# app that accesses the Microsoft Graph API.
So far I have used InteractiveBrowserCredentials.
Unfortunately, I have to reconfirm them every time I start the application.
Therefore I would like to bypass this.

I have also seen that it is possible to log in with a ClientSecret.
So I think the best option would be this.

I have created this secret in my Azure portal and copied the secret value (not the Secret ID) into my Code.
Now when I query data I get a meaningless error message.

> An exception of type "Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError" was thrown.
>
> Message: "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token."
>
> Code: "AccessDenied"

My code looks like this:

```
string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential("TENANT_ID", "CLIENT_ID", "VALUE_OF_SECRET");
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
```

Is there anyone with similar problems?

Comment: Could try yo debug your code and check the details of ODataError? Please share at least ODataError.Error.Code and ODataError.Error.Message

Comment: I have added the message and the code to the post. 
Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the stored API permission in the Azrue portal.

So far I had only stored permissions of the type Delegate.
After I changed this to Application, the access with the application also worked.

With the new permission I had to execute "Grant admin consent for COMPANY_NAME".